# GWT 'xyz' Project : Generate war/xyz folder

Tags: gwt

My project's name is for example 'xyz' , in the war file the compiler has to create the xyz folder and .nocache.js , hosted.html , .cache.png etc. But I think sometimes the compiler doesn't create all the needed files and it causes the "GWT module 'xyz' may need to be (re)compiled" problem when I deployed my project to tomcat server.
What I want to ask is , how can I create all the files by myself or make the compiler create all the needed files? I tried to use speed tracer. But I am not sure if it is right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *"GWT module 'xyz' may need to be (re)compiled"* message is symptomatic of running a `xyz.nocache.js` generated by the DevMode rather than the Compiler.

Things to check:

- if there's no `*.cache.js` or `*.cache.html` in your `war/xyz` folder, then you didn't run the Compiler (at all)
- if there are but it still generate the error, then you might have run the DevMode after you run the Compiler, and made some changes to your `xyz.gwt.xml` file (in that case, the DevMode will overwrite the existing `xyz.nocache.js`, otherwise it keeps it around).

In any case, run the Compiler to fix the issue. If you're using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, that's the red toolbox icon, **not** the blue circle.